# Interpretation of BASIC line

Tags: basic

I have had to OCR an old bit of BASIC code which contains this line:

[image: A BASIC line of code]

which I have interpreted as:

```
10140   FOR K = 1 TO NS: FOR J = 1 TO NN:A%(CJ%(J),S%(K)) = 1 * (A%(CJ%(J),S%(K)) = 1 OR A%(CJ%(J),N) = 1): NEXT J,K
```

I thought I knew BASIC way back when, but I am confounded by what's happening after the second colon.

Could it be conversion of a boolean into an integer by multiplying it by "1" ?

Comment: Old BASIC implementations didn’t tend to have booleans; do you know what environment(s) that code was targeted for? I simplified it into the simple BASIC program `10 INPUT A%, B%:X% = A%=1 OR B%=1:Y% = 1*(A%=1 OR B%=1):PRINT X%, Y%:GOTO 10` to see what differences result. I tested this on a TRS-80 Model 1 emulator and a Commodore 64 emulator and there doesn’t appear to be any difference in those limited cases.

Comment: What output do you get for X% and Y% ?  The same or different?

Comment: No difference. Both are “-1” (true) or “0” (false) depending on whether either `A%` or `B%` is “1”. In those environments, multiplying the “boolean” by 1 does not seem to make a difference.